# operator overloading ; must be a binary operator(with 3 parameters)

Tags: c++

I am trying to change the 2D Self-avoiding random walk to 3D. But I am getting the error 'operator overloading'. Can someone help me to resolve the issue? My code is attached below.

```
struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;

};

struct Data
{
  int nSteps;
  int maxX;
  int maxY;
  int maxZ;
  int maxRSq;
  int endX;
  int endY;
  int endZ;
};



bool operator == (Point p1, Point p2, Point p3){ **// Operator overloading(must //have binary operator(with 3 parameters))**
  return ((p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y) or (p1.z == p2.z));
}
```

Comment: How can a *binary* operator have three operands?

Comment: Maybe replace `or` with `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You can't define `operator==` with three parameters. Think about every other time that you've seen `==` used, it always has two parameters.

Seems that what you want is something like this

```
bool operator==(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y && p1.z == p2.z;
}
```

That version says that points `p1` and `p2` are equal if their x, y and z coordinates are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The == operator takes two arguments only (not three).

When defining it inside the class one argument is *this* and the other one is defined inside the parameter list like this:

```
bool operator ==(const Point& b) const;
```

If you now want to compare three objects you have to call the operator twice:

```
(p1 == p2) && (p2 == p3)
```